# android - не запускается apk после установки

Tags: android, исключения, android-manifest

При обычной сборке через кабель приложение работает нормально, при установке apk - вылетает ошибка:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer, PID: 32695
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.Welcome}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.Welcome" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.Welcome" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1070)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.Welcome
                                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                            ... 12 more
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Проверял пути к классам в манифесте - написаны правильно. 
Весь код очень большой и несколько коммитов назад приложение нормально устанавливалось с apk. Вот мой манифест:

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Welcome"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- android:screenOrientation="landscape" -->

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewerFile"
        android:label="@string/viewer_file"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewerImage"
        android:label="@string/viewer_file"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

также чистил и собирал проект заново - не помогает

Comment: А вы с нуля ставите на устройство программу или поверх старой? И как вы получаете apk?

Comment: Да, попробуйте удалить старую и с чистого листа поставить эту. Бывает иногда

Comment: каждый раз перед установкой apk удаляю старую. а apk беру из папки app/bild/output

Comment: Соберите apk принудительно из студии и потом из той папки куда он его положит перенесите на устройство

Comment: попробуйте закоментировать использование класса `ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.Welcome` или проверьте правильность его пути

Comment: @plesser, так и делаю.

Comment: @Vitaly путь правильный